# SALib.analyze.delta: What is the definition of the return parameters delta and delta_conf?

Tags: python

I wanted to implement a sensitivity analysis on given input and output data in python. The design of the input parameters is based on Latin hypercubes, so I decided to use the delta module of SALib. I can not find some documentation what exactly is the meaning of the return parameter delta, delta_conf, S1, S1_conf.

Does somebody know the definition and thereby how to understand the results?

The documentation of the package referres to some papers, but i have no access.

```
.. [1] Borgonovo, E. (2007). "A new uncertainty importance measure."
       Reliability Engineering & System Safety, 92(6):771-784,
       doi:10.1016/j.ress.2006.04.015.

.. [2] Plischke, E., E. Borgonovo, and C. L. Smith (2013). "Global
       sensitivity measures from given data." European Journal of
       Operational Research, 226(3):536-550, doi:10.1016/j.ejor.2012.11.047.
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The DELTA of an individual parameter (or of a group) can assume
values between 0 and 1. 
It will equal 0 when Y is
independent of the parameter (or group of parameters) at
hand. 
It will equal 1 when the group including all inputs is
considered.

DELTA = 0              If Y is independent of Xi

SUM OF DELTAS =1       The importance of all parameters equals unity

DELTA represents the normalized expected shift
in the distribution of Y provoked by Xi.

"S1" is the sobol First-order indices: it measures the contribution to the output variance by a single model input alone.

S1 represents the influence of a parameter on the VARIANCE of the output.
DELTA represents the influence of a parameter on the DISTRIBUTION of the output.

Source: Borgonovo, E. A new uncertainty importance measure. Reliab. Eng. Syst. Saf. 92, 6 (2007),
771–784.